# Python: numpy.memmap zeros, reusage, documentation?

Tags: python, numpy

Is a numpy.memmap array initialized with zeros? Where is this documented? Can the contents of an already existing **old** numpy.memmap file (**from a previous execution of the script**) be loaded into a new numpy.memmap rather than replaced by zeros? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried any of that?  what happened?

Comment: zeros behaviour [documented in the source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/memmap.py) in the Notes section.

Comment: Thank you @wwii ! See my full comment under the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `memmap` `doctest` examples seem to be pretty clear about this:

```
Create a memmap with dtype and shape that matches our data:

>>> fp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='w+', shape=(3,4))
>>> fp
memmap([[ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]], dtype=float32)
```

The data in the freshly created file is all zeros

later after writing and closing

```
Load the memmap and verify data was stored:

>>> newfp = np.memmap(filename, dtype='float32', mode='r', shape=(3,4))
>>> newfp
memmap([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  4.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
        [  8.,   9.,  10.,  11.]], dtype=float32)
```

The data in the existing file carries over from the last use.

---

In the source

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/memmap.py

```
 def __new__(subtype, filename, dtype=uint8, mode='r+', offset=0,
            shape=None, order='C'):
    ...
    if mode == 'w+' or (mode == 'r+' and flen < bytes):
        fid.seek(bytes - 1, 0)
        fid.write(np.compat.asbytes('\0'))
        fid.flush()
```

If I'm reading that correctly it is writing a 0 at the start of the file (or the end of the existing file).  `mmap.mmap` may determine what is done with the rest of the desired length.

Comment: Documentation by examples can be confusing and incomplete. I'll state the answer here explicitly: `mode='w+'` initializes with zeros [on systems with POSIX filesystem semantics](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/memmap.py); all other mode values initialize with the old memmap file contents. Thank you @hpaulj and @wwii