# Why is numpy.memmap initialization so fast?

Tags: python, numpy, mmap, numpy-memmap

numpy.memmap [initializes with zeros (on systems with POSIX filesystem semantics)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32029300/#comment52022088_32030234).

Then how can it take only 0.3 seconds to fill a 10 GB file with zeros like this:

```
n = 10000000000
f = np.memmap('tmp.mmap', dtype='uint8', mode='w+', shape=(n, 1))
f[-1] = 1  # set some value
del f  # flush changes
f = np.memmap('tmp.mmap', dtype='uint8', mode='r', shape=(n, 1))
```

Writing 10 GB to disk usually takes longer than 0.3 seconds.

Comment: also, `%` afaik is not the comment character in Python. Please use `#` to avoid confusion...

Comment: And whitespaces are for free. Using whitespaces can drastically improve code readability.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala there's no confusion. jupyter users are kinda common here